# Django DateField Query

Tags: django, datetime

I am new to Django (1.4.1) and I have a model like this:

```
class Expediente(models.Model):
    numero_expediente = models.IntegerField()
    ano_expediente = models.IntegerField()
    data_expediente = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    urgencia = models.IntegerField()
    complexidade = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    numero_copia = models.IntegerField()
    posse = models.IntegerField()
    grupo = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

And I'm trying to do a query with a date range:

```
now = datetime.now()
lista_expedientes = Expediente.objects.all().order_by('ano_expediente'

data_inicio = datetime.combine(now+timedelta(-30), now.timetz())
data_fim = datetime.combine(now, now.timetz())

exp_antiguidade[0] = lista_expedientes.filter(data_expediente__range=(data_inicio,  data_fim))
```

I have tried queries with `__gte` `__range` and others, but at the end I always have a error:

> Exception Type: TypeError
>
> Exception Value: an integer is required

I think that I need to convert the datetime to an integer...

Any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis after ...order_by('ano_expediente'... is this a typo? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data_expediente` is a `DateField`, so it expects a valid `Date` object, but you are giving a `Datetime` object. You must fix the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.today().date() # get a Date object
data_inicio = now + timedelta(days=30)
```

Comment: @Herrmann can you update the question and write it again with your corrections?